# want to access child properties with parent class id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

i am new in spring boot. i have hotel class and address class. relation between hotel and address is one to many. i want to search addresses with hotel id.

Hotel Class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Address> address;
```

Address class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private Hotel hotel;
```

controller:

```
@GetMapping("/search/{hotelId}")
public String searchAddressHotel(@PathVariable("hotelId") Long hotelId, Model model){

    List<Address> addresses= addressService.findAddressByHotelId(hotelId);
    model.addAttribute("addresses", addresses);

    return "address-list";
}
```

view:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Road Number</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">Country</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="address: ${addresses}">
            <th scope="row" th:text="${address.id}"></th>
            <td th:text="${address.roadNumber}"></td>
            <td th:text="${address.city}"></td>
            <td th:text="${address.country}"></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {
        List<Address>findAddressByHotel(Long hotelId);
}
```

when i am searching with this link ( localhost:8080/search/1 ) in browser, show this exception:

```
2019-07-22 14:33:09.340 ERROR 12216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.shaon.SpringBootLogin.model.Hotel (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.shaon.SpringBootLogin.model.Hotel (n/a)]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.shaon.SpringBootLogin.model.Hotel (n/a)]
```

why hotel id did not match with hotel id column in address table. please help me.

Comment: Can you check my answer, hope that is helpful for you! I gave an efficient answer where you don't need to select the parent to select the children again, directly can get children with parent id as you have needed.

Comment: hmm, adding `spring rest repositories`  will do job for you and you even do not even have to write query xd

Comment: thanks to all. i have solved my problem. actually the problem was in the repository. i had a little bit problem about the custom method. now all are ok.

Comment: @mdshaon Can you please give a feedback on my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AddressRepository your search addresses by hotel, so you need to pass Hotel object to your repository. If you want to search by hotel id, you should create findAddressesByHotelId method. Try these two possibilities :

```
List<Address>findAddressByHotel(Hotel hotel);

List<Address>findAddressByHotelId(Long hotelId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first select `Hotel` with `hotelId` then get addresses from it, but it might be unnecessary to select parent if you don't need it. You can redesign your entities as following to make it easy to fetch children entities with parent key;

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Embeddable
    public static class Pk implements Serializable {

        @MapsId
        @Column(name = "hotel_id")
        private String hotelId;

        @Column
        private String addressId;

        // getter & setters
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private Pk pk;

    @JsonBackReference
    @MapsId("hotelId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id", referencedColumnName = "hotel_id", nullable = false)
    private Hotel hotel;

    // getters & setters
}
```

& use this `hotelId` in `Address.Pk` for selecting with parent key;

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

    List<Address> findByPk_HotelId(Long hotelId);
}
```